# How to "expose jenkins" to the internal network

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've installed a jenkins docker image on my CentOS7. When I type

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

There is an error :[Jenkins Initial Setup is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI8T8.png)

Since my CentOS7 does not have a graphical interface, do you know how do I "expose" it in order to see the renderized jenkins interface in another machine ?

I tried reading some documentation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/services/) but I really don't know where and how these configurations are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow external access to port `8080` by opening your Firewalls if you have any. Then Simply access it like `http://IP_OF_THE_JENKINS_SERVER:8080`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer @ycr. I just gave it a try: firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp firewall-cmd --reload and it worked. Thank you!